# Parse error code 121

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am trying to save a value on a 'collection' called 'orders'. But when i click 'save', it gives me an error code 121.
I have already checked my key-value parameters, but i can't find a $ or a . to make it give me this error...
Here is my code (the variable names are in portuguese, but only that)

```
var objRevenda = Parse.Object.extend("resellers"),
    objPedido = Parse.Object.extend("orders"),
    query = new Parse.Query(objRevenda),
    idRevenda = $scope.revenda.id;

query.get(idRevenda, {
    success: function(revenda) {
        var valores = {
            status: 'aberto',
            client: $rootScope.usuarioAtual,
            reseller: revenda,
            payment_method: metodo_pgto,
            items: $scope.itens,
            total: $scope.totalPedido
        };
        var pedido = new objPedido();
        pedido.save(valores, {
            success: function(pedido) {
                console.log('Sucesso');
            },
            error: function(pedido, error) {
                console.error('Ops... ', error);
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(revenda, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Can someone help me find the error?

Btw: I am using AngularJS and Ionic Framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just before calling .save, can you console.log(valores)? That should help you figure out exactly what is being sent.

Comment: Okay, so i logged the 'valores' and it gives me an object... I think Parse only goes with JSON right? I tried converting the object to JSON, but with no success either.

Comment: The thing is, this error is telling me i can't use $ or . in a key or value. None of my keys/values have $ or . Plus, i tried putting the $scope variables into other variables as string, but no success either

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am unable to find a faulty key.

Comment: Anyone know of a god way to debug this? Maybe some function to search the characters of the keys and nested keys of the object.

Comment: I figured out that if you are using angular (maybe other frameworks as well) that an embedded object id on multiple levels will result in a $$hashKey key being created and will cause this error.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a JSON object (sending it to Parse via AngularJS), it will have a `$$hashKey`, wich Angular uses to make ng-repeats and all, having unique identifiers. If you use `JSON.Parse(object)`, Angular creates the `$$hashKey`, altough, if you use `angular.toJson(object)`, the hash key should be gone. Make sure that before sending to Parse, you do a `console.log(json-object)`, to make sure the hash key is really gone. If not, i think you should remove it by doing a conditional operation. I removed the hash key and now it works like a charm ;)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that if you are using angular (maybe other frameworks as well) that an identical embedded key/value pair on multiple levels will result in a `$$hashKey` key being created and will cause this error.

Maker sure that none of your objects contain something like the following:

```
{
  id: 65ftvjbh,
  user: {
            id: 65ftvjbh,
            name: John Doe
  }
```

Comment: Is it any pair? or just identical id value?

Comment: I have not tested. I would assume any pair because the system should not know which value is the id in my case.

Comment: I just found out that this $$hashKey is also created when you do the JSON.Parse() function, wich i was doing. If you use angular.toJson() it should be fine ;)
Make sure that your object doesn't have a $$hashKey by doing console.log()